# Convert nested lists to data.frame using all recursive indexes as colnames and fill missing columns with NAs

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have been struggling with this for a day now and all research made in SO doesn't seem to produce the result that i need.

I have this list:

```
    input_list <- list(
        list(A = 'a1', B = 'b1', C = 'c1', D = 'd1'),
        list(A = 'a2', C = 'c2', D = 'd2'),
        list(A = 'a3', B = 'b3', C = 'c3'),
        list(A = 'a4', B = 'b4', C = 'c4', 
             D = list(
                sub_1 = "d4_1",
                sub_2 = "d4_2")
             )
    )
```

Basically I want to turn it into this structure:

```
#tbl_df
#A  B  C  D  D.sub_1  D_sub_2
#a1 b1 c1 d1 NA       NA
#a2 NA c2 d2 NA       NA
#a3 b3 c3 NA NA       NA
#a4 b4 c4 NA d4_1     d4_2
```

I tried messing with map function:

```
output_list <- input_list %>% 
    map(unlist) %>% 
    do.call(rbind.data.frame, .)
```

It correctly unlists all nested lists converting them to named vectors, but I'm stuck as to how to `rbind` the rows matching the column names and fill missing variables with NAs.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this. You can use `unlist()` with `lapply()` to unnest the values and then transform to dataframe each element using `as.data.frame(t(...))`. Finally, `bind_rows()` from `dplyr` can bind the elements as you expect. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- bind_rows(lapply(input_list, function(x) as.data.frame(t(unlist(x)))))
```

Output:

```
   A    B  C    D D.sub_1 D.sub_2
1 a1   b1 c1   d1    <NA>    <NA>
2 a2 <NA> c2   d2    <NA>    <NA>
3 a3   b3 c3 <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
4 a4   b4 c4 <NA>    d4_1    d4_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map_dfr` :

```
purrr::map_dfr(input_list, as.data.frame)

#   A    B  C    D D.sub_1 D.sub_2
#1 a1   b1 c1   d1    <NA>    <NA>
#2 a2 <NA> c2   d2    <NA>    <NA>
#3 a3   b3 c3 <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#4 a4   b4 c4 <NA>    d4_1    d4_2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `unnest_wider`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
tibble(col = input_list) %>% 
     unnest_wider(c(col)) %>%
     unnest_wider(c(D))
```